# Failed to convert value to MediaStream

Tags: reactjs, html5-video, screenshot, mediastream

I am trying to implement Screen Capture API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture#capturing_screen_contents

I am building the same code in React JS,

when I place the following code I am getting an error **"Failed to set the 'srcObject' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': Failed to convert value to 'MediaStream'."**

````
<video id="video"></video>
video = document.getElementById("video");
video.srcObject = navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);```


Please someone help in resolving this issue
````

Comment: did you try to use async/await : do video.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions)

Comment: can you share the whole code, or error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<video id="video"></video>
```

JS

```
video = document.getElementById("video");
 
async function startCapture() {
  

  try {
    video.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
  } catch(err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
  }
  return captureStream;
}
startCapture()
```

Comment: working I tried with out asyn and await